# Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741701 (0xC000007B)

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Android emulator is killed when started from avd manager. I am running a flutter project. flutter -doctor below

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.450], locale
    en-IN)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available
```

There are no devices available since I have created them but not able to run them.
Few things I have already tried:

1. Set java jdk, android ndk and sdk
2. Set java jdk and android sdk in environment variable
3. run adb kill-server and adb start-server from inside the avd folder